# How to return Object from ComboBox

Tags: mysql, combobox, javafx-2

I have a problem with retreiving item from combobox... So, the main idea is that my dialog returns an BookDetail object so i can insert it into database. In this dialog i have combobox for my Category class - i expect it to return to my constructor in BookDetail a Category object which is selected item from combobox.
I have already values from my category_table in combobox but i can't implement selected Category object into BookDetail constructor... there is a lot of code in this block so i will show only frustating block.

I want in that constructor where you can see now "categoryBox1" to put there selected Category object from combobox. Does someone can give me advice or example how to correctly do that? I can't find answer...

```
private void addBook() throws SQLException{
Dialog<BookDetail> dialog = new Dialog<>();

Label categoryLabel1 = new Label("Category: ");


dataCategories = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); // table with categories
ComboBox categoryBox1 = new ComboBox(categoryOptions);
categoryBox1.setMaxHeight(30);

String sql = "select * from tbl_category";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next()){
    dataCategories.add(new Category(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));
} 

categoryBox1.setItems(dataCategories);

dialog.setResultConverter(new Callback<ButtonType, BookDetail>(){
        @Override
        public BookDetail call(ButtonType b){
            if(b == buttonTypeAdd){

                return new BookDetail(isbnText.getText(),authorText.getText(),categoryBox1,
                        titleText.getText(),publisherText.getText(), dateOfPublicationText.getText(),
                        Integer.parseInt(ratingText.getText()),commentsText.getText());
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the the selected (or user edited) value of the ComboBox by calling [getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--).

So, in your `BookDetail` constructor, instead of passing in the ComboBox itself via the `categoryBox1` reference, instead just pass in selected value from the combo box:

```
categoryBox1.getValue()
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! :)